# angular-ui-router v 0.4.2 with Angular 1.6.1

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am basically trying to make a simple routing:
where i have defined the following in app.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("productManagment", ["common.services", "ui.router", "productResourceMock"]);
    app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider","$locationProvider",
        function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider ,$locationProvider) {
           $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
           $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/products');
            $stateProvider
                .state('/products',
                {
                    url: '/products',
                    templateUrl: 'app/products/productsView.html',
                    controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
                });
        }
    ]);
}());
```

i am using angular js 1.6.1 and angular-ui-router v 0.4.2 .
my index html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--Library scripts here-->
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="common/services/common.services.js"></script>
    <script src="common/services/productResource.js"></script>
    <script src="common/services/productResourceMock.js"></script>
    <script src="app/products/productListCtrl.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body ng-app="productManagment">

            <div ui-view></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

while the product list view is :

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="font-size: large"> Product List</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
                                ng-click="vm.toggleImage()">
                            {{vm.showImage ? "Hide" : "Show"}} Image
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>Product</td>
                    <td>Code</td>
                    <td>Availability</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
                    <td>
                        <img ng-if="vm.showImage" ng-src="{{product.imageUrl}}"
                             style="width: 50px; margin: 2px"
                             title="{{product.productName}}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.productCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.releaseDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i try to run the application, it should be routed to the "/products" along with its template, but i got the below error from the developer tools of chrome:

> 

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/products/productsView.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fproducts%2FproductsView.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at handleError (angular.js:19730)
    at processQueue (angular.js:16648)
    at angular.js:16692
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17972)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17786)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18080)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1841)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4842)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1839)
```

the network tab shows:
[image]

Comment: Well, stupid question but does `app/products/productsView.html` exists? Do you run your application on a Webhost? (e.g. not `file:///` protocol in browser..). Please add the view file code of `productsView.html`.

Comment: yes , it exists.
i am using visual studio's IIS Express.
the application was working normally before i try the routing, where i have added the div of the productListView in stead of the ui-view

Comment: Just for ensure your route is correct: you are able to get the view while calling `http://yourhost/app/products/productsView.html` in your browser? Please add the view template to your question.

Comment: just added it .
i am able to get the view  when calling "http://yourhost/app/products/productsView.html" from the browser but for sure all of angular directive are not working

Comment: I dont think its depending on your directives. Does it work if you change your template view to `<h1>Hello world</h1>`. I realy think your routing source path is not correct. Are you running your application in an subfolder like `http://yourhost/app`?

Comment: yes .
and when i replace the view to include only a header of hello world as your example , and call the following on my browser:
[link] http://yourhost/app/products/productsView.html
it is working normally.
but when try to use the routing still the same error

Comment: Ok, please take a look in your browser tools at network tab - which HTTP status is thrown when you router tries to load `app/products/productsView.html`?

Comment: there is nothing shown in the network tab, for the load of the template .
only index.html productListCtrl.js, ..etc

Comment: Please look again. there must be a get request fired in the moment you switch to state `/products` which tries to load `app/products/productsView.html`

Comment: Please check the "disable cache" button  + "preserve log" in your network tab and try again.

Comment: have updated the picture

Comment: still the same error in console? Have you tried it with a simple template like `<h1>Hello world </h1>`?

Comment: Please join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135439/discussion-between-lin-and-user1874288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of reproduction we were able reproduce were the problem was comming from. The `ngMock` configuration was blocking nearly any request fired by the client. We could solve the problem by allow AngularJS [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) to GET sources in the following directoy `app/views/*` which results in the following pattern:

```
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/app/*/views\//).passThrough();
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the problem was caused because of the usage of MockE2E.
so if I make something like $httpBackend.whenGET("/app/products/productsView.html").passThrough();
it is not intercepted by the mock.